# Modify code, which searches for a certain word in a tex and ads a span class to it, to work with arrays

Tags: php

Please take a look at this code (thanks to user budwiser), it matches a certain word in a text and ads a span class to it:

```
function highlightWord($word, $text){
    return str_replace($word, '<span class="highlighted">' . $word . '</span>', $text);
}

$text = highlightWord('fitness', $text);
```

Any ideas how to make this code work for arrays?

I'd need something like this:

```
$words = array("fitness", "aerobic", "fashion");

$text = highlightWord($words, $text);
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

**UPDATE**

```
$profile_rule = 'profile LIKE (\'fitness\') AND profile LIKE (\'aerobic\')';
preg_match_all('/\'(.*?)\'/',$profile_rule,$match);
```

Any idea why $match array does not work?
I want to extract the words fitness and aerobic from the $profile_rule and use the $match array for the function above.

Ty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick. Simply iterate over the words and add the highlight code.

```
function highlightWords(Array $words, $text)
{
   // Loop through array of words
   foreach($words as $word)
   {
      // Highlight word inside original text
      $text = str_replace($word, '<span class="highlighted">' . $word . '</span>', $text);
   }

   // Return modified text
   return $text;
}
```

Comment: Wow, give me a few minutes to test it, is Array with Caps on A?

Comment: I can't remember, I think I've used it both ways. That is just type hinting anyway, it's not necessary.

Comment: Ty very much, it worked, I am updating the code with a question, maybe you can help, 1 moment please. ty

Comment: Pleasure;) ty very much, I'll post it